# How can I initialize an array declared in main in another function

Tags: c++

I want to declare a vector in main dynamically because I don't know how much elements will contain, the elements are inserted from keyboard by an user. The array must be initialized (assign values) in another functions ex: inputDataInVector .

I've tried creating a pointer in main and I pass it to the other function.

```
void inputDataInVector (int v[])
{
    int i = 0; value = 0;
    while(value != -1)
    {
         cin >> value;
         v[i] = value;
         i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int v[] = {0};
    int *p = v;

    inputDataInVector(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected result: Add elements in array as the user writes the numbers 
Actual result: Array v remains at length 1, keeping only first value introduced

Comment: Who told you that arrays can change their size? What you should be using is a vector not an array.

Comment: C++ != C, pointers != vectors. Pick a language and learn the idiomatic way of using it.

Comment: c or c++? Pick a language first please.

Comment: An array without size is no valid C code. Please pick your language properly. C is not C++.

Comment: @Gerhardh It's not valid C++ either. I think it did used to be valid C. Anyway, use of `cin >> value;` is definitely not C.

Comment: Can I allocate memory dynamically while the user is inputting values in array ? Let's say allocate 5 ints and if the number of values > this memory to allocate five more ? Thanks!

Comment: @lookster123 That's exactly what `std::vector` does..

Comment: @lookster123 Yes you can, if you did that you'd be writing code similar to what std::vector does for you.

Comment: Prefer to use something like `while(cin >> value && value != -1)`. It ensures that `cin >> value` produced a valid result before trying to use it. Also remember that when C++ streams fail, they stay failed until you address the problem by `clear`ing the error flags and removing the condition that caused the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with a vector, unlike an array a vector can change it's size

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void inputDataInVector(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    int value = 0;
    while (value != -1)
    {
         std::cin >> value;
         v.push_back(value); // this changes the size of the vector
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    inputDataInVector(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always a good idea to try to compile your code before you post an answer - this has several errors.

Comment: Still has problems. What happens if `std::cin >> value;`  fails?

Comment: @NeilButterworth can you please explain what do you mean by `std::cin >> value;` failing ?

Comment: @lookster `std::cin >> value;` will fail if you try to read something like "foobar" - the code will then enter an infinite loop. Your code must test every single input operation to see if it worked, and if it didn't, handle the problem somehow.

Comment: @lookster123 user4581301 in the comments above has the best way to write this loop